# What are different between two ways of initial MutableLiveData in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

Both Code A and Code B init a variable MutableLiveData.

In my mind

`_playA` can be null, and `_playA?.value` can not be null

`_playB` can be null, and `_playB?.value` can be null

right?

**Code A**

```
private val _playA = MutableLiveData(EPlayState.STOPPED)
```

**Code B**

```
private val _playB = MutableLiveData<EPlayState>()
```

**Both**

```
enum class EPlayState {
    STOPPED,
    PLAYING,
    PAUSED
}
```

**Added content**

From the prompt information in Android Studio, you will find `val a` and `val b` can be null.

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **LiveData** or **MutableLiveData** is just a wrapper over your actual data. Data can be any type.
You wrap your data with LiveData so that when the **value** in **LiveData** changes, it trigges the **Observer** listening  to it. (For better understanding see **OBSERVER DESIGN PATTERN**)

**Now answering your questions,**

> _playA can be null, and _playA?.value can not be null
> _playB can be null, and _playB?.value can be null
> right?

Both play `_playA and _playB` cannot be null as you've already initialized them with **MutableLiveData**.

`_playA and _playB` are referring to the **instance** of the **MutableLiveData**.

> From the prompt information in Android Studio, you will find val a and val b can be null

Yes, both `val a and val b` can be null beacuse **they're referring to the **value** held by the MutableLiveData** and not to the instance of **MutableLiveData**.

As, **MutableLiveData and LiveData** is a wrapper class (that is, holds another class), we can initialize a  **MutableLiveData** by specifying the type it should hold.

**Example-**
`val isBool:MutableLiveData<Boolean>=MutableLiveData()`

In this case,  `isBool.value` will give **null** since only the **type** has been specified but no value has been set.

But

When I do,
`val isBool:MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(true)` // passed a boolean value to MutableLiveData constructor

`isBool.value` will give **true** as I had initialized it with Boolean value **true**

**Same stands in your cases.**

Answer (score -1):

You are right that when calling

```
private val _playA = MutableLiveData(EPlayState.STOPPED)
```

`_playA.value` *is* not null. BUT it *can* be null after calling `_playA.setValue(null)`

As the others already said, the MutableLiveData object itself will not be null as you initialized it. But as you said, in theory you could still call `_playA = null` and therefore it *can* be null.